# Merging Two Tables Including INDIRECT Function in Excel and Displaying New Table Data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, office365

### Dynamic Variables Explained

Data is pulled at the end of each month and is stored in the format of `YYYY.MM.DD -- Monthly Data Obtained.xlsx` and Excel calculated the date range.

```
=TEXT(EOMONTH((EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)),-1),"yyyy.mm.dd")&" -- Monthly Data Obtained.xlsx"
=TEXT(EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1),"yyyy.mm.dd")&" -- Monthly Data Obtained.xlsx"
```

> 2021.08.31 -- Monthly Data Obtained.xlsx
>
> 2021.09.30 -- Monthly Data Obtained.xlsx

I can then call to one of the tables by using indirect;

```
=INDIRECT("'["&TEXT(EOMONTH((EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)),-1),"yyyy.mm.dd")&" -- Monthly Data Obtained.xlsx"&"]Sheet1'!Table1")
```

---

### Merging The Two Tables

The first column of each table is the unique primary key, however one table may have several members the other table does not. For the new table, I would like to only include those who are in both files, and I would like the two data columns to be calculated to see the figure for that month. The daily and weekly are somewhat basic sums I've added based on the new data;

- `=[@Total]/TEXT(EOMONTH((EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)),-1),"dd")` - Divides total by amount of days in previous month.
- `=[@[Daily Avg]]*7` *- Times daily by 7.*

[image]

---

### Questions

1. How can I combine both tables implementing the INDIRECT function to only show all `members` who are present in both files?
2. Calculate the difference in value for the above members?

Comment: I would combine the tables using Power Query (available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365).  You can do what is called an Inner Join to report only members available in both.  Exactly how to get the data into Power Query depends on a lot of information you haven't provided. But combining the two tables you show is pretty simple.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I have Office365 and Power Query, something i've never heard of before, seems like something to really look into! Thank you for this. What additioanl information would help improve my question please? In each file each month, it is going to be a basic table, like seen in the image above, nothing special, `file 1` represents one month, `file 2` another, and then there is the merged table in the new file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain the tables from the files using Power Query. You can do that in a variety of ways which, now that you are aware of the tool, you can do some research on.

I will show an example of what can be done once you have the two tables. In my workbook, I have Named them Table32 and Table33, but you can easily change that.

There are other aspects of the code you may want to change or add -- this is just an example of some of the possibilities.

[image]

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in either on of your Data Tables
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in the two lines that start with `Source=` and `Source1=`.
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table names in those lines back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

```
let

//Read in first table and get date from column 2 name
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table32"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Member", type text}, {Table.ColumnNames(Source){1}, Int64.Type}}),
    dt1 = Date.From(Table.ColumnNames(Source){1}),

//read in second table and get date from column 2 name
    Source1 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table33"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source1,{{"Member", type text}, {Table.ColumnNames(Source1){1}, Int64.Type}}),
    dt2 = Date.From(Table.ColumnNames(Source1){1}),

//calculate number of days
    days = Duration.TotalDays(dt2-dt1),

//join the two tables only with names from both
    join = Table.Join(#"Changed Type","Member",#"Changed Type1","Member",JoinKind.Inner),

//compute the total by subtracting the earlier dated column from the later
//then remove the dated columns
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(join, "Total", each [2021.09.30]-[2021.08.31]),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"2021.08.31", "2021.09.30"}),

//Add Daily column = Total/number of days between the dates
//and Weekly = 7*Daily
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Daily", each [Total]/days),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Weekly", each [Daily]*7),

//set data types and reorder the columns
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom2",{{"Daily", Currency.Type}, {"Weekly", Currency.Type}}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Changed Type2",{"Member", "Total", "Weekly", "Daily"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

[image]

- much of the code, but not all, was generated by the UI
- some of the code refers specifically to the Date column headers in the two tables.
- it is certainly possible to edit the code to have it refer to columns in certain positions, instead of the hard-coded names
- My math shows different results than your screenshot. Perhaps you are computing the days differently? I calculated it using the difference in the date headers of the two columns.  For you example, that would be `30` which, for Peter, I calculate a Daily of `90/30=3` whereas you show `2.89`.  But the math is easily changed once I understand the rules you are using.

Comment: Does this method allow the `INDIRECT()` feature to be used to always open the previous month, or in future versions, I would like to implement a drop down to select the month, so another variable based fetching of files. The table columns, I would then dymanically obtain too, using eh code I added on my question. I have had some complications and am only just being able to come back to this. My apologies for my delay and thank you for your help!

Comment: As I wrote: *"I will show an example of what can be done once you have the two tables."* This has nothing to do with `INDIRECT`. I would suggest using a different method to obtain your tables, but that is a topic for another question.

Comment: Where I appreciate your response, I am clearly looking at using `INDIRECT()` or, potentially another method where I can call for information in another file via a variable, and then to combine the two tables. This is what I have stated in my question title and question therewithin. Your comment on my question to look at Power Query was more in the right direction, not to post an answer and say it is not about something I am looking to do.

Comment: @TimorhyMarshall you can obtain the tables using PQ as well as by other methods. I focused on the merging part of your question since your wording suggested to me that you were able to get the tables using your method but were having problems merging them. If that is not the case, I'll delete my answer.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I have been having some problems outside of this, I just want to say that I haven't really got round to fully looking into what you have explained to me.